# Python server does not accept JSON sent by jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, python, http, jquery, cgi

I would like to use JSON to manage data between client/server. However, everything works except JSON...
I think it come from my python server, but I am not specialist in server programming so I really don't know how to change in my python server. My python server is really simple because I really don't know how to program inside. 
If I don't use JSON it works perfectly but it is not really efficient to get sort the data.
Is there a easy way to modify my python server to accept json (if it comes from python server)?

Here is my html:

```
<form method="post" id="formu" >
        <textarea class="field span10" id="sequence" name="sequence" cols="4" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // formular
            $('#formu').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
                var sequence = $('#sequence').val();

                $.ajax({
                            url     : 'test.py',
                            type    : 'post',
                            data    : JSON.stringify({'sequence' : sequence}),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success : function(data){
                                    alert(data);
                                        } // end of success function
                        }); // end of ajax

            });
        });
```

My python code for ajax (test.py):

```
import json
result = {'myresult':'lalalalalal'};

myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
result['fromclient'] = myjson['sequence']
print 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
print json.dumps(result)
```

And my python server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svg", True)
mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svgz", True)
mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/javascript", ".js", True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/plain", ".txt", True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/html", ".html", True)
mimetypes.add_type("application/perl", ".pl", True)
mimetypes.add_type("application/json", ".json", True)




server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 8080)
#handler.cgi_directories = ['/FOLDOMEweb']
handler.cgi_directories = ['/WEBSERVER'] 
httpd = server(server_address, handler)

try:    
    print "Running HTTP server"
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Server Stoped"
```

Comment: You're mixing CGI and an long-running, daemon, web server. How did you intend to run your web server?

Comment: I just run python server with "python myserver.py" on my shell and it works except the JSON. After I can open in localhost.../mypage.py

Comment: You haven't described anywhere what "doesn't work" means. What goes wrong, and where, in what circumstance, and what were you expecting to happen there?

Comment: When I submit, I don't receive data in my test.py in any case, there is no crash just nothing happens. If I remove JSON in ajax and get my data in test.py simple with form =cgi.FieldStorage() and form.getvalue('sequence') ajax works perfectly well! But I would prefer use JSON, I am sure it comes from my python server that not accept json, but I don't know how to tell it to accept it...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
data    : JSON.stringify({'sequence' : sequence})
```

and pass the object to the jQuery ajax call. It'll handle the formatting itself. Remember form values are comprised of name, value pairs - so let jQuery do that for you.

Comment: but if I want to give other argument such like {'sequence':sequence, 'secondarg':"mysecondarg"} how to do? If I remove the line it still doesn't work. The Json does not work. If I don't use Json it works why ?

Comment: define the object with any properties you need - then pass it inside the `data` argument